# Jade/Pug: non-empty optional argument

Tags: pug

Here is the standard method of the passing optional arguments in JADE/PUG mixin:

```
mixin TestMixin(id)
    - id = id || ''
    div(id=id)
```

However, in the case of HTML ID, it should not be empty. If we have the empty ID, we should not add this attribute. I checked the Jade/Pug conditionals [docs](https://pugjs.org/language/conditionals.html), but there are not enough the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great case for an if/else conditional.

```
mixin TestMixin(id)
  if id
    div(id=id)
  else
    div
```